# connect to the database as the window loaded

Tags: c#, wpf

i am trying to establish  database connection using  SQL CE 3.5SP2  in WPF C#.

i want to connect as soon as windows loaded . so   i selected Windows_loaded event  and and the connection. the Code as Follows .

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlCeConnection con = new 

    SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Master.sdf");

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Established");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Failed");
        throw;
    }
}
```

My Problem is :  Windows is taking bit of time to load ( may be it is first connecting to database and then loading the window)

it's not problem when connection is established  but if there is any connection error  . the error message is first displays then on clicking OK to message box the windows loads.

i want to  eliminate this error . but want  windows to connect to database just after it is fully loaded and i want to inform the connection process in progress bar at status bar .

what is the option available for should i use Threading  or Background worker  or custom event handler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do all your stuff in a method like

```
public void Adddatasource()
{
SqlCeConnection con = new 

    SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Master.sdf");

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Established");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Failed");
        throw;
    }

}
```

and now in  the page load event

```
App.current.Dispatcher.beginInvoke(dispatcherPriority.Backround , new action(adddatasource));
```

this  will load in backgound and your page will be loaded too..

Answer (score 1):

You need to run database connection code in a separate thread (BackgroundWorker is better approach over Threading but it is only my opinion) and within thread use dispatcher to update UI elements (like status bar etc). You can find some good examples from this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all

1- why do you want to establish a connection in window load ? If you can remove this constraint that would be great in my guess  you will be populationg some data in window load so i think you you would have some controller or ViewModel than use ViewModel to populate the data and use Binding framework to bind the data.

2- If point 1 is not possible than You can use BackgroundWorker to delegate the task , it supports report progressing and all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like following should work:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Master.sdf");

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((obj) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.IsEnabled = false;
        }));            

        try
        {
            con.Open();

            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Established");
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Failed");
            }));
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.IsEnabled = true;
            }));
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: i tiried this but getting an error as follows    InvalidOperationExexption   .   Pointing at   " this.IsEnabled = false;"   - The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.